# How can I understand $x(b)=x(a)+\int_a^{b}f(s,x(s))\,ds$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand this integral form of the ordinary differential equation:

$$x(b)=x(a)+\int_a^{b}f(s,x(s))\,ds\quad\text{for }a\leq t\leq b$$

I tried to pick a concrete example:

Let $x(s)=s^2$ and $f(t)=x(s)+s=s^2+s$

But it does not make sense if we say: $x(b)-x(a)=\int_a^{b}s^2+s\,ds$

So what is wrong with my example? How can I give a better example?

Also, how can I understand the equation in the first place without using any example?

Hope anybody can give me some help. Thanks!

Comment: your equation "define" a relationship between $x$ and $f$, as such your example does satisfy the defined relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your differential equation is $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$. This strongly connects $x$ and $f$ as solution of the given ODE. In this context the integral equation is just stating the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
x(b)-x(a)=\int_a^b x'(s)dx=\int_a^b f(s,x(s))ds.
$$
And $x(t)=t^2$ is not a solution of $x'(t)=x(t)+t$